# opengl error: Unhandled exception at 0x0251D09F (ig4dev32.dll) in GLTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl

i want to get opengl version,the code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Version");
    const char* version = (const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    printf("OpenGL version：%s\n", version);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

but i get the error in `glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Version");`,who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the default graphics driver provided by Microsoft. To use OpenGL, you have to install drivers provided by your graphics card manufacture.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question by update my Graphics driver,the url is:http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18223/a08/win7_1512754.exe