# Unhandled exception at 0x0292D09F (ig4dev32.dll) in Start Dock.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl

I was starting a project and decided to use some openGL. I keep getting this error and cannot figure out why.

Additional Info:
For my IDE I'm using VS 2012
I have also recently upgraded to win8 for my OS.

Here is my src:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_FPS = 60;

int main(int argcp, char** args)
{
    glutInit( &argcp, args );
    //Create Double Buffered Window
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126341/opengl-error-unhandled-exception-at-0x0251d09f-ig4dev32-dll-in-gltest-exe-0x

Comment: @Cong Xu - I have already seen that and updated my drivers. Is there anything else?

Comment: Which line does the error occur?

Comment: Do other OpenGL programs work?

Comment: @molbdnilo Im not sure but openGL previously worked on windows 7.